# Custom navigation bar's button doesn't work (SwiftUI)

Tags: swiftui, uinavigationbar, navigationbar, swiftui-navigationlink

I am currently learning SwiftUI and I followed this video to create a custom NavigationBar.

[Learn how to create a custom navigation bar with a logo in SwiftUI framework and Xcode - Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NQ8svUpTKwY)

The buttons doesn't work when I click on it unless I don't use padding() and ignoreSafeArea(), but without using it, the navigationBar would appear on middle of the page. (I also tried use Spacer() but it didn't work)

Is there anyway to fix this issue?

Code for HomePage()

```swift
 VStack{
    NavigationBarView()
      .padding(.horizontal, 15)
      .padding(.bottom)
      .padding(.top, UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.top)
      .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.1), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 5)
      .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .top)
```

Code for NavigationBarView()

```swift
HStack{
                
  NavigationLink(
    destination: PersonalMenuPage()
    ,label: {
      ZStack {
        Image("Profile")
          .renderingMode(.original)
          .resizable()
          .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
          .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
          .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                            
          Circle()
          .fill(Color.red)
          .frame(width:14, height: 14, alignment: .center)
          .offset(x: 13, y: -10)
          }
         }
      )
 }//: hStack
```

Here is sample output
[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6sXT.png)

Comment: You aren't showing a lot of code here. Do you have it in a 'NavigationView()`? Other than that it is difficult to answer your question with the information given. Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).